# How to make hibernation work again on 15.10 after disabling encrypted swap

Tags: encryption, swap, hibernate

on my clean install of Xubuntu 15.10 I am **unable to make hibernation work, although it's been working** on my laptop successfully since 11.10 or so.

The only thing changed is that I have selected "encrypt home" during install and so I have it encrypted. But I noticed swap was also being encrypted. OK, so it couldn't work.

So I decided to unecrypt my swap in order to make hibernation work again.

What I did:

> sudo swapoff -a
>
> sudo cryptsetup remove /dev/mapper/cryptswap1
>
> removed the only line in /etc/crypttab
>
> sudo /sbin/mkswap /dev/sdaX
>
> sudo swapon /dev/sdaX
>
> removed the line with "/dev/mapper/cryptswap1" in /etc/fstab and replaced it with "UUID=d30170d7-b3a2-41b5-a389-541a6d0013c7 none swap    sw  0   0" (new UUID taken from the mkswap's output)
>
> reboot

tried `sudo pm-hibernate` again with no luck :/ - after booting-up several apport errors have been generated...

So, please, any hints how to make it work again? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Solution: the problem was in `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` where was still some wierd old UUID. After replacing with the new one and invoking `sudo update-initramfs -u` it works now!

Maybe if I just did these steps, it would work:

1. comment-out the line with `/dev/mapper/cryptswap1` in `/etc/fstab` and
   enable the line with UUID under the `# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation line` (= enabling swap with no encryption)
2. comment-out the only line in `/etc/crypttab`
3. edit `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` in order to contain the swap's UUID from `/etc/fstab`
4. `sudo update-initramfs -u`
5. reboot and check