# Hibernation with Ubuntu 16.10 fails

Tags: hibernate

After upgrading from ubuntu 16.04 to 16.10 the hibernate function no longer works. When hibernate is invoked the machine hangs. Under 16.04 it worked perfectly. Trying "sudo pm-hibernate" also fails.

Comment: Please give hardware details.

Comment: At times like this it's a good time to learn where system error messages are stored. Looking '/var/log/syslog' is a good place to start. Then copy and paste anything that looks relevant into your question... Thanks.

Comment: It did  not work in 16.04 for a few months if you installed kernel updates.

Answer (score 2):

I've come to the same issue very recently (this week or the previous). What has been working for me is combination of @richbl s answer somewhere just here around, @morhook answer [in this thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/487282/208566) and my own answer [in this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697316/how-to-make-hibernation-work-again-on-15-10-after-disabling-encrypted-swap/697324#697324). I post it all here to have it in one place.

What I did to **make the hibernation work again** on my ASUS U36SD running Xubuntu 16.10 "Yakkety Yak":

1. Stop using `sudo pm-hibernate` - it is not working any more.
2. Modify the `/etc/default/grub` so that the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` variable contains also `pci=nomsi resume=UUID=XXXXXXXX`, where XXXXXXXX is the UUID of the swap partition. To determine the UUID of your swap, use:

   ```
   lsblk -o name,fstype,uuid
   ```

   Full example here:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=nomsi resume=UUID=d30170d7-b3a2-38c5-a386-541a6d0013c7"
   ```
3. Update the new grub configuration:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
4. Create a new file `com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla` in `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/`:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla
   ```

   and fill it with this content:

   ```
   [Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
   Identity=unix-user:*
   Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
   ResultActive=yes

   [Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
   Identity=unix-user:*                            
   Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions
   ResultActive=yes
   ```
5. If you are using encryption, you must tweak it a little bit more - it is [well described here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697316/how-to-make-hibernation-work-again-on-15-10-after-disabling-encrypted-swap/697324#697324).
6. Reboot the computer.
7. You should now be able to see the hibernate option in the poweroff menu and it should work.

Comment: I've made a bugreport on launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pm-utils/+bug/1641919

Comment: Unfortunatelly, in my case, this works only for first hibernation after fresh boot :/ Any next hibernation would fail ending-up with a login screen like if I had just locked the desktop

Comment: With the above I have the same issue, only the first hibernation works. However  subsequent hibernations will cause the machine to hang.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernation does not work with UEFI Secure Boot enabled on new Ubuntu kernels for security reasons.

You need to disable Secure Boot if you want to use hibernation.

Comment: Negative. I've UEFI disabled completely in my BIOS and I am experiencing the same issue.

Comment: You may have other reasons why hibernation does not work. But it will never work with Secure Boot enabled.

Comment: @Pilot6: That's good to know. Do you have a source which explains it further? Thinking of updating [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html).

Comment: I saw the explanation somewhere, but I did not keep a link. I see it in the sources.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's better to post [a link that might solve your problem](https://askubuntu.com/a/849167/32664), or to repost that solution below:

---

Since you're running Ubuntu 16.04, you should consider running the [native systemd suspend/hibernate services](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/systemd-sleep.conf.5.html) in lieu of the pm-utils tools.

In my own case, here's what I've done to configure my machine for hibernate/resume using systemd:

1. In `etc/default/grub`, configure `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to include
   the resume parameter, passing the UUID of the swap partition in
   question (i.e., resume=UUID=453f0121-505d-42d3-8dad-87f913e67ddc). My
   current GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT is

   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash **pci=nomsi resume=UUID=453f0121-505d-42d3-8dad-87f913e67ddc**"
2. Run *sudo update-grub*
3. Edit/confirm resume=UUID=453f0121-505d-42d3-8dad-87f913e67ddc entry
   in resume file located in `/etc/initramfs`
4. Run *sudo update-initramfs -u*
5. Edit `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` to set HandleLidSwitch=hibernate (optional: permits hibernate to start on lid close)
6. Run *sudo service systemd-logind restart*
7. Reboot for good measure

I've bold-faced the two parameters that--for my machine--are important: `pci=nomsi` and `resume=UUID=[your swap partition]`. While the latter parameter is pretty well understood and is often refenced when talking about enabling hibernate on a Debian system, it took a bit of discovery to find the need for the former.

Best of luck!

Comment: For future reference: copy information here into answers from appropriate sources -- so it's *here* and so in case the other end goes away, it's here :)